# Print the whole webpage in a single image file

Tags: web-browser, screenshot

Sometime, we encounter a long webpage and at the same time, we need to screenshot. However, it is difficult to screen shot since it is a long webpage and need to screenshot multiple times and later merge them as one single image.

So, is there a special web browser or tools that allow one to screen shot a single long webpage into a image file and have the ability to control the quality of the image (such as the percentage of compression for JPG format)?

Comment: What is your regular webbrowser? Or do you need a tool thats independent of that?

Comment: And on which operating system?

Comment: N. B. Jpeg is not good for text shots at all, use PNG instead.

Comment: Firefox has screenshot tool right? Press Ctrl+Shift+K , that'll bring up console , look for settings icon on right side (should be 4th from last) , click on it and scroll down to the end. On the left-downmost side , you'll see 'Take a fullpage screenshot' , mark it and you'll have screenshot icon ready with that console. So anytime you have to take a screenshot , press Ctrl+Shift+K and click on that screenshot(camera) icon. And Chrome can print Pdf from web pages too. No need for plugins if browser has inbuilt functions for that.

Answer (score 15):

It only does PNG, but Firefox has a way to capture the whole page built in: Shift-F2 brings up a command prompt, which includes a `screenshot` command. For instance, `screenshot --clipboard --fullpage` as I was writing this answer produced https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXbgW.jpg.

If you want something designed to be automated, phantomjs has [`page.render()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/render.html) which takes a filename and an optional options object, with `format` and `quality` entries; the example given is

```
page.render('google_home.jpeg', {format: 'jpeg', quality: '100'});
```

Comment: Sounds very interesting – but are you sure about the hotkey? Pressing Shift-F2 doesn't bring up anything for me here (FF35). Also: Is this feature documented somewhere, where one can read more?

Comment: Ah. Didn't work on FF35 on windows, but does on Linux :) And for a list of commands one has simply to type `help` (or `help <command>` for more details). Good to know, +1 for that – though I don't understand why it's not working on Windows.

Comment: Interesting about the `screenshot --clipboard --fullpage` when use on firefox. However, seems not working when capture this whole page `http://blog.bahraniapps.com/gifcam/`

Comment: @user275517 Thats a fascinating site, Nimbus is equally unable to screen shot the whole page

Comment: @AngeloFuchs Looks like there is no software to screen shot this whole page `http://blog.bahraniapps.com/gifcam/`

Comment: @user275517 Not true, I tried the print to file function and it produced a pdf that contained that, so it must be possible (somehow). Maybe we should file a bug report :)

Answer (score 10):

I use [Nimbus Screenshot](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/nimbus-screenshot/?src=api) a plugin for my Firefox for this task.

You can right click any page and say "make a screenshot of the whole page" and it will.
It will open the screenshot in a new tab and allow you to modify it.

Then you hit "Done" and can save it to your hard disk, clipboard, in their cloud (and more).

As example, here is a screenshot of this very page:

[image: screenshot]

Their Options bar looks like this (screenshot made with Nimbus, because it can do "selected area" screenshots as well).

[image: Nimbus Menu]

Comment: upvote, because I needed the firefox capability :)

Comment: Which you didn't state in your question ;-)  Or is it just "nice to have"

Comment: @Mawg tls is not the OP of the question :)

Comment: Nice to have too :) I can never get enough screen capture programs.

Answer (score 5):

I upvoted the answer from @tls, as that is also my tool of choice, after having tried many, many, screen-capture programs.

However, you might also consider trying "print to file". IIRC; the default Windows print to file only supports text, but you can Google around for one that supports graphics.

The big advantage of this is that you don't need to launch an extra application, just use the Print menu.

In fairness, though, FastStone Screen Capture let's you crop and annotate, which can be useful.

[One of the first hits](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php) prints to PDF (Goggle further if you want anther format).

> The Bullzip PDF Printer works as a Microsoft Windows printer and
>   allows you to write PDF documents from virtually any Microsoft Windows
>   application.
>
> This program is FREEWARE with limitations, which means that there is a
>   FREE version for personal and commercial use up to 10 users. It does
>   not contain any advertising or popups. For commercial applications
>   with more than 10 users there are commercial versions available with
>   advanced features.

```
Features
```

- Print to PDF from almost any Windows program.
- Supports 64-bit operating systems.
- Direct output to the same file each time or prompt for destination.
- Control if the printer should ask if you want to see the resulting PDF document.
- Control output and prompts programmatically.
- Setup can run unattended.
- Graphical user interface.
- Password protect PDF documents.
- AES 256/128 bit encryption and standard 128/40 bit encryption.
- Quality settings (screen, printer, ebook, prepress).
- Set document properties.
- Watermark text, size, rotation, and transparency.
- Superimpose/background documents.
- Appending/prepending documents.
- User interface control.
- Linearized PDF documents for fast web view.
- PDF/A-1b support for long time storage of PDF documents.
- Signing of PDF documents using digital certificates.
- Command line interface to all settings.
- COM/ActiveX interface for programmatic control.
- Microsoft.NET API for C#, VB.NET, and other .NET development.
- Support for Citrix MetaFrame
- Support for Windows Terminal Server
- Multiple output types supported: BMP, JPEG, PCX, PDF, PNG, and TIFF.
- Upload document using FTP or SFTP protocol.

Comment: upvote as well, having more than one choice is always better :)

Comment: Did you use this way? My experience with "print to file" are bad. The last time I tried it (some years ago) on a routing site (think google maps) the resulting page was nothing like the one I saw on screen, because what the "printer" thinks it sees and what the browser thinks it sees are different.

Comment: Well, you can only try it and see. Is it worth a few minutes?

Comment: @Mawg Well, do you or do you not use this method? And also: No. If I just want to try everything a few minutes I don't need to ask for a Recommendation, do I?

Comment: Yes. It works 100% for me. YMMV

Answer (score 3):

FastStone Capture http://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?id=775 has exactly what you need. It is also portable. Note however that the last freeware version (v5.3) might have some problems with the Firefox browser rendering engine. However I get great results capturing the entire page using IE and the latest version of Google chrome browser.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I use **FireShot**: http://getfireshot.com/ It's a browser plugin, available for most browsers.

From their website:

> Capture full web page screenshots in Firefox, Chrome, Opera or IE, and
>   then edit and save them.

They have a free version which does all of the above, including capturing very long pages. It also has a built in editor which allows basic image manipulation. The pro version has some more editing and annotation features.

Comment: Despite the name ??

Comment: @Mawg: I gueess he means that is not only for Firefox

Comment: @Mawg It once was Firefox only, but not anymore. I will remove that part in the answer, as it seems only to confuse.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use [phantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html) for such tasks. It can be used to take screenshots programmatically where I can even specify the size of the image, the user agent to be sent to the web-server and other related things.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any of the fine tools mentioned here. All you need is Google Chrome since it allows you to print the current page to PDF no matter how long the page is. This feature is built into Chrome. So if you use Chrome, you already can easily capture many web pages into a PDF just as if you had printed it to a physical printer.

Answer (score 2):

PicPick, which is available free as a portable app from [PortableApps](http://www.portableapps.com), is a multi-function utility that includes screen capture.  One of the screen capture modes is Scrolling Window, which does what you want.  The standard version is at [PicPick Home page](http://www.picpick.org).  The portable version About window shows it as free for personal use. The single user purchase price for the standard is $21.99 to $24.99 (they show a limited time offer on their Buy Now page at the moment).  It includes an editor that can be used to mark up the screen shot as soon as it's captured.  It should work with any browser.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Full Page Screen Capture](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screen-capture/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl) Chrome extension. It allows you to create full height screenshots.

Comment: Does it "have the ability to control the quality of the image", as the OP requested?

Comment: It makes PNG files. Most of webpages using PNG graphics to dispaly images, also PNG is best for capturing text. Using Jpeg compression makes text unreadable.

Comment: JPEG as well as PNG offer different settings for quality/compression. OP explicitely asked for that: "such as the percentage of compression for JPG format". Using a different file format is a completely different thing, even though it plays a little role indeed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running OS X, there is a little utility program that's been around forever called [Paparazzi!](https://derailer.org/paparazzi/) that does what you're looking for. It's very customizable (including batch-capturing screenshots of multiple URLs), and can export JPG, PNG, PDF, and TIFF files.

When I'm not on OS X, I also use the [Awesome Screenshot Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-screenshot-captur/alelhddbbhepgpmgidjdcjakblofbmce). It's nice because it allows you to annotate your image before you save it.

Unfortunately neither of these options has compression options built-in, but I hope they'll still be helpful to you.

Comment: If someone uses OS X, mostly is enough simply print the page and save it to PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Use this [Full Page Screen Capture](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screen-capture/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl) for Chrome.

I had tested on my machine, here is the snapshot of it (click for original size):

[image: Example screenshot, made with Full Page Screen Capture]

As you can see clearly the picture quality is not degraded.

Answer (score 0):

Use WebToPDF firefox addon which will generate a PDF and Image both.Click [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/webtopdf/) to know more

Answer (score -1):

Firefox browser Addon for full web page screen shot

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/fireshot/

All details how to use available on above link. Install the addon

Comment: Same as under your other answer: please do not use link shorteners on Stack Exchange sites. And please explain why a tools meets the OP's requirements. Link-only answers are not very helpful.